# Embedding YouTube with WP-AppKit

Tags: wordpress, plugins, youtube

I created an android application from the wordpress with plugin WP-AppKit. All works well except that the youtube video is not displayed

I do not know what to do? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube videos inserted in WordPress by copy/paste the YouTube video's URL (using oEmbed) are iframes.

By default, WP-AppKit strips iframes from its web service responses.

**You have to specifically allow iframes to be part of the web service response.**

In order to do that:

- Create a *php* subfolder in your app's theme folder (if you don't have one already)

  - Create a .php file in that subfolder (eg. allow-iframes.php)
  - Copy/paste this Gist in your .php file: https://gist.github.com/blupu/71732457596168d851d2
  - Refresh your app's content and the video should appear now (however, you'll have to properly handle it to let it be responsive)

What the Gist code does is hooking the WP-AppKit's web service answer to allow iframes in the allowed tags returned by the web service.

Regards.